# javascript jquery url part trimming

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a url like

```
http://www.blah.com/something/maybesomethingelse/Webservices/something.asmx/blah
```

That is being passed through a jquery ajax request.

I want to remove everything after /Webservices/ so I can stick a new page in for error handling.

so ideally this would return

```
http://www.blah.com/something/maybesomethingelse/Webservices/
```

Then i could just concat on the new page.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Simple way: url = url.split(/\/Webservices\/)[0]+"/Webservices/"+yourstuff

Comment: You want to do this in Javascript?

Comment: @mplungjan: that *comment* seems worthy of being an *answer* +1 for the comment, and an up-vote on your answer (should you post it) =]

Comment: @David: Thanks :) I was sure that if I posted it, some jQuery or RegEx purists would downvote it as far as they could ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple way: `url = url.split(/\/Webservices\/)[0]+"/Webservices/"+yourstuff`

or neater

```
var lastFolder = "/Webservices/";
url = url.split(lastFolder)[0]+lastFolder+yourstuff;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a parser like this one:

http://stevenlevithan.com/demo/parseuri/js/

but in this simple case, you only need to find the last index of "/Webservices/":

```
var lastIndex = url.lastIndexOf('/Webservices/')
```

and then take everything from the beginning up to the end of "/Webservices/":

```
var baseUrl = url.substring(0, lastIndex + 12)
```

and then append the new page:

```
var newUrl = baseUrl + '/Error.aspx'
```